# Get a reference to a Python object while iterating over a complex dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, reference, assign

I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this little problem. I want to iterate over a complex Python data structure (dict, list, tuple, strings, bytes, ...) and replace all bytes (byte strings) with a base64 encoded version. This is necessary to convert the original complex data structure to JSON (e.g. `json.dumps(complex_data_structure)`) since JSON does not support binary data. My code already does the right thing but there is one Python-specific problem. Here is my code:

```
import sys
import json
import base64


def iter_object(obj):
    if type(obj) is tuple:
        iter_tuple(obj)
    elif type(obj) is dict:
        iter_dict(obj)
    elif type(obj) is list:
        iter_list(obj)
    else: # non iterable types except of string and bytes etc.
        if type(obj) is bytes:
           # THE PROBLEM IS THE COPY OF OBJ!
           obj = base64.b64encode(obj).decode("ascii")
        else:
            pass # we don't care about other data types


def iter_tuple(obj_tuple):
    for t in obj_tuple:
        iter_object(t)


def iter_list(obj_list):
    for l in obj_list:
        iter_object(l)


def iter_dict(obj_dict):
    for k, v in obj_dict.items():
        iter_object(v)


def main():

    test_dict = {
        "foo": [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        "bar": 1,
        "baz": (1, 2),
        "blub": {
            "bla": b"\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41",
            "ble": {
                "blu": [
                    1, 3, b"\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42",
                    (1, [b"\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43"])
                ]
            }
        }
    }

    iter_object(test_dict)

    print(json.dumps(test_dict))

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

The problem is the line `obj = base64.b64encode(obj).decode("ascii")` because it works on a copy not a reference (to say it in C++). Here is my question: **Is there a workaround to make the above code work?**

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Works on a copy?? No. What is happening is that the function is returning a value instead of changing it in place. This is because **byte strings are immutable.** There is no concept of pass by value or reference in python. The variables are not boxes which hold objects, they are rather *names* of some object. And object can be

1. Mutable - `list`, `set`, `dict`
2. Immutable - `tuple`, `str`, `bytes`

So if a function acts on Immutable object it has to return another object. The memory usage is optimized. And this is the defacto way in languages like Haskell.

Comment: Thanks, for you answer. Is there any solution to the problem so that the above code runs correct as intended? I can't imagine that there is no way to solve the problem in Python. Can I take another approach or is there a workaround for that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem:

```
import sys
import json
import base64

class BinaryToBase64Encoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, bytes):
            return base64.b64encode(o).decode("ascii")
        return super(BinaryToBase64Encoder, self).default(o)


def main():

    test_dict = {
        "foo": [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        "bar": 1,
        "baz": (1, 2),
        "blub": {
            "bla": b"\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41",
            "ble": {
                "blu": [
                    1, 3, b"\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42",
                    (1, [b"\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43"])
                ]
            }
        }
    }

    print(json.dumps(test_dict, cls=BinaryToBase64Encoder))

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

The JSON output is:

```
{
    "foo": [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    "baz": [1, 2],
    "bar": 1,
    "blub": {
        "ble": {
            "blu": [
                1,
                3,
                "QkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkI=",
                [
                    1,
                    ["Q0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0M="]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "bla": "QUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUE="
    }
}
```